# self publishing - what are the steps from end of writing to publication?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, book

I have written a book on affirmations and now am looking for the steps that will take me from here to self-published.  Is it a 1. line editor, 2. development editor, layout editor, book cover design? No sure if all these steps are needed and by whom.  Any advice

Answer (score 1):

A development editor will give you the big picture, so you start there before hiring a line editor. If you are not a book designer, you can hire a designer who will set the font and look of the pages. You'll need to check out various book publishers, whether print or ebook or both. Here's a good site to check out all these avenues: https://blog.reedsy.com/